# How do you use a TimerTask to run a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, timertask

I'm struggling to find documentation for the TimerTask function on Android.
I need to run a thread at intervals using a TimerTask but have no idea how to go about this.
Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You use a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), and that automatically creates a new Thread for you when you schedule a `TimerTask` using any of the `schedule`-methods.

Example:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000L);
```

This creates a Timer running `myTimerTask` in a Thread belonging to that Timer once every second.

Comment: The above code creates a `Timer` running the task in a thread _only once_ after one second. To run a task once every second, use this overloaded `schedule` method: `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`. For example, `timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000L, 2000L)` creates a timer that runs every 2 seconds after initial delay of 1 second. Here is the link to the method [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, long, long))[link]

Comment: The link was formatted wrongly in the above comment. Here is the corrected link for the [methods of Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 72):

I have implemented something like this and it works fine:

```
    private Timer mTimer1;
    private TimerTask mTt1;
    private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();

    private void stopTimer(){
        if(mTimer1 != null){
            mTimer1.cancel();
            mTimer1.purge();
        }
    }

    private void startTimer(){
        mTimer1 = new Timer();
        mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){
                        //TODO
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: What is the 1 in schedule?

Comment: The 1 in schedule is the amount of time in milliseconds before the first execution of the scheduled TimerTask. The 5000 is the amount of delay in between subsequent executions in milliseconds.

Comment: Please mind that this invokes the Runnable on whatever thread this class was created on.

Answer (score 12):

This is perfect example for timer task.

```
Timer timerObj = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTaskObj = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       //perform your action here
    }
};
timerObj.schedule(timerTaskObj, 0, 15000);
```