# Timer not working in Android when calling invalidate()

Tags: android, timer, ondraw, flashing, android-view-invalidate

I want to create a flashing effect by drawing a path with color grey, white (matching to the background), and then grey again. I want to flash 3 times, showing gray for 1 sec, white for 1 sec gray again for 1 sec, etc.

When I created a `Handler` for `postDelayed()`, the program skipped over the run() and did not execute it in the timing set, and no flashing occurred:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                invalidate(); //calls onDraw()
                Log.d(TAG, "Flashing now now");
            }
        }, 1000);
```

How would I implement such a flashing functionality with a timer and flash it 3 times?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try timertask ?

Comment: How would I do that? Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.

int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

public void run() {

System.out.println("done}

}, delay, period);
```

Otherwise you have plenty other examples to follow like this [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029831/how-do-you-use-a-timertask-to-run-a-thread), [Example 2](http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/), [Example 3](http://d-codepages.com/android-timertask-example/) etc. Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code example of how we flash a globe from blue to red and back again.  You can modify the code on the inside to limit how many times and what time delay you want.

```
protected MyGlobeFlasherHandler handlerFlashGlobe = new MyGlobeFlasherHandler(this);

@Override
protected onCreate(Bundle bundle) { 
       handlerFlashGlobe.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 700);
}

/**
 * private static handler so there are no leaked activities.
 */
protected static class MyGlobeFlasherHandler extends Handler {


        private final WeakReference<HomeBase> activity;

        public MyGlobeFlasherHandler(HomeBase activity) {
            this.activity = new WeakReference<HomeBase>(activity);
        }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        if (activity.get() != null) {
            if (activity.get().shadedGlobe) {
                activity.get().imgData.setImageDrawable(activity.get().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.globe_blue));
            } else {
                activity.get().imgData.setImageDrawable(activity.get().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.globe_red));
            }

            activity.get().shadedGlobe = !activity.get().shadedGlobe;

            sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 700);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Kristy, here you are animating by using two distinct images. That isn't very good programming practice; ideally, you would want to set a .png file and programmatically change the color by perhaps using `setIndent()`.

Comment: @Eddev Can you tell me what you mean by "bad programming"?  Also, the image is a photo and I can't imagine changing the color prgrammatically.