# Thread.stop() is deprecated. But how to use TimerTask instead?

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, timertask, java-threads

I have started a **thread** on press of a toggle button. Now I want to stop that thread on pressing that toggle button again. But `Thread.stop()` API has been deprecated. So, I am getting UnsupportedOperationException. I don't know how to use **TimerTask** as an alternative to it. Here is my sample code:

```
//AudioDispatcher implements a Runnable
public class AudioDispatcher implements Runnable

//This is a code to start a thread
AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
Thread t1 = new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher");
t1.start();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a TimerTask to run a thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029831/how-do-you-use-a-timertask-to-run-a-thread)

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply stop a thread in mid execution. If you want to stop a thread in mid execution then you can call `Thread.interrupt()` method.

```
public class SomeBackgroundProcess implements Runnable {

Thread backgroundThread;

public void start() {
   if( backgroundThread == null ) {
      backgroundThread = new Thread( this );
      backgroundThread.start();
   }
}

public void stop() {
   if( backgroundThread != null ) {
      backgroundThread.interrupt();
   }
}

public void run() {
    try {
       Log.i("Thread starting.");
       while( !backgroundThread.interrupted() ) {
          doSomething();
       }
       Log.i("Thread stopping.");
    } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
       // important you respond to the InterruptedException and stop processing 
       // when its thrown!  Notice this is outside the while loop.
       Log.i("Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");
    } finally {
       backgroundThread = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a flag and stop according to flag

```
 class Server implements Runnable{
      private volatile boolean exit = false;

      public void run() {

     while(!exit){ 
        System.out.println("Server is running....."); 
    } 

    System.out.println("Server is stopped...."); 
    } 

    public void stop(){ exit = true; } 
}
```

start and stop now

```
  Server myServer = new Server(); 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(myServer, "T1"); 
    t1.start(); 
//Now, let's stop our Server thread 
System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " is stopping Server thread"); myServer.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this time task sample;

```
private static final int DEFAULT_DELAY_TIME = 1000;
private static final int DEFAULT_PERIOD = 1000;
private Timer mPlayTimer;
private TimeTask mPlayPlanTask;

private void startTask() {
        configTimer();
        mPlayTimer.schedule(mPlayPlanTask, DEFAULT_DELAY_TIME,
              DEFAULT_PERIOD);
    }
}

private void stopTimer() {
    if (mPlayTimer != null) {
        mPlayTimer.cancel();
        mPlayTimer = null;
    }
    if (null != mPlayPlanTask) {
        mPlayPlanTask.cancel();
        mPlayPlanTask = null;
    }
}

private void configTimer() {
    if (null == mPlayTimer) {
        mPlayTimer = new Timer();
    }
    if (null == mPlayPlanTask) {
        mPlayPlanTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  // Do some work;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop runnable by your self or can not stop a thread you can interrupt your thread by calling `Thread.interrupt()`. Extend your `AudioDispatcher` to `Thread` rather than `Runnable` an override `interrupt()` if you need to release some resources.

```
public class AudioDispatcher extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // check if thread is interrupted do nothing
        if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        super.interrupt();
        // release resources if any
    }
}
```

Now start your thread by

```
AudioDispatcher audioDispatcherThread = new AudioDispatcher();
audioDispatcherThread.start();
```

When you need to stop your thread call `audioDispatcherThread.interrupt()`;