# run timerTask on not ui thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, timertask

I got timerTask which calls every 500ms. Every time it calls it freeze my ui thread for a moment. My question is how to make it runs in not UI thread?

```
mTimer.schedule(keeper, 0, 500);

private class PlayerKeeper extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {}

        });
```

Comment: `doInBackground`??

Comment: No matter, it must work as a timerTask and do not freeze ui:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a TimerTask to run a thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029831/how-do-you-use-a-timertask-to-run-a-thread)

Comment: Use Countdown timer , although you can use TimerTask too. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android)